# Sigma Delta Sampling

Tags: analog-to-digital, delta-sigma

I am using a Sigma Delta ADC and really understood the working of it
I need to sample a signal at 8.5 Mhz.
The SD ADC has a Demodulator and decimating FIR filter
The Oversampling ratio options are 32/64/128/256 and FIR filter has 32 taps
What should be OSR ratio and how to determine the FIR coefficients
Thanks

Comment: Which converter are talking about?  Are you sampling the signal/information at 8.5mhz  or is this the internal clock and cycle rate of the converter?

Comment: Dear Sir, I need to sample at 8.5 Mhz and its a 12 bit SD ADC

Comment: I meant manufacturer and model number:)

Comment: We are using a processor that supports SD ADC and that has these variables.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't get a grasp of your application; but I think the following will be helpful: http://electronicdesign.com/analog/understanding-delta-sigma-modulators -- it seems to cover the different facets of  oversampling.

Comment: whole point of sigma delta means COMPARE the signal with sum of quantized previous samples.